# How do I retrieve data in INT form from a database with codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I am trying to create an update function that adds an entered value to the value for the user in a database.  (It adds accounts that can be used for a class to a teacher)  So far, I have a test button that should add one account when it's clicked and then refresh the page.

Here is my function thus far:

```
public function add_account()
{
    $this->load->model("teacher_data_model");
    $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
    $user_id = $user->id;
    $data = array(
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'unused_accounts' => [what do I insert here?]
    );

    $this->teacher_data_model->add_accounts($data, $user_id);
    redirect('teacher', 'refresh'); 
}
```

This function is admittedly sloppy, I am still fairly new to this.  This function gets the user ID and passes it to a model that uses it to find our teacher and update the number of student accounts they have.  So far this works as long as I have a fixed value for 'unused_accounts', the problem is when I do this:

```
public function add_account()
{
    //  Getter of the user data
    $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
    $user_id = $user->id;
    $this->load->model("teacher_data_model");

            //This gets the existing accounts
    $num_accounts["record"] =    $this->teacher_data_model->get_unused_accounts($user_id);
    $this->load->view("teacher/teacher_data_viewer", $num_accounts);


    $data = array(
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'unused_accounts' => [what do I insert here?]
    );

            // data insertion
    $this->teacher_data_model->add_accounts($data, $user_id);
    redirect('teacher', 'refresh'); 
}
```

I'm not sure whether to but the +1 increment in the controller or the model, but I can't even seem to identify the searched data as an int at this point.

For [what do I insert here?] if I use $num_accounts I get this database error:
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

UPDATE `teachers` SET `user_id` = '1', `unused_accounts` = Array WHERE `user_id` = '1'

Here is my model in case it's needed:

```
function add_accounts($data, $uid)
{
    $this->db->where('user_id', $uid);  
    $this->db->update('teachers',$data);
}
```

EDIT:  This is my function that gets the data from the database

```
function get_unused_accounts($usersid)
{
    $this->db->select('unused_accounts');
    $this->db->from('teachers');
    $this->db->where('user_id', $usersid);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

I'm not sure if this puts out data in INT form.  When I was using this to check if the user has at least one account, it always accepts as true even if the user has zero accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using raw SQL in your model for this purpose:

```
function add_accounts($uid, $quantity = 1)
{
    $this->db->query('
        UPDATE teachers 
        SET unused_accounts=unused_accounts+'.$quantity.'
        WHERE user_id='.$uid
    ); 
}
```

Now you can increment `unused_accounts` value by one for a user using

```
$this->teacher_data_model->add_accounts($user_id);
```

or by any amount you want using

```
$this->teacher_data_model->add_accounts($user_id, $amount);
```

Not sure if CodeIgniter's ActiveRecord would accept statement `unused_accounts=unused_accounts+'.$quantity.'`, but if it does, you can try using this in your controller **it wont work, see below for an edited part**:

```
 $data = array(
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    'unused_accounts' => 'unused_accounts + '.$amount
);
```

**EDIT:** Looks like if you want to use ActiveRecord, you must use `$this->db->set()` with a third parameter set to FALSE, so something like this in your model:

```
function add_accounts($unused_accounts, $uid, $amount = 1)
{
    $this->db->where('user_id', $uid);
    $this->db->set('unused_accounts', 'unused_accounts+'.$amount, FALSE);
    $this->db->update('teachers');
}
```

Comment: I used the raw SQL and it worked perfectly, as did the edit with ActiveRecord.  The help is much appreciated.

Comment: I ran into something else; I think it may have to do with how I am getting the data out of the table.  When I try to test if the user has less than one account, it auto accepts it as true.

if($remaining_accounts = 1)
{redirect('teacher/teach_show_students','refresh');}

Answer (score 1):

Cant answer comments yet but

```
if($remaining_accounts = 1)
```

Will allways be true, try:

```
if($remaining_accounts == 1)
```

See [PHP manual for comparison operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)